# Use non-absolute Paths with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, path

i'm having issues running my node server on localhost. 
right now it only allows me to run it with a static path:

```js
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        res.sendFile("/Users/name/Documents/_privat/dungeon/index.html");
    });
```

of course that's not where i wanna go.

i tried many ways to embedd the dynamic path, this is my file-structure:

```js
*dungeonapp
 - main.html
 - js
  --client
   ---main.js (and others)
  --server
   ---server.js
 - style
  --style.css
```

So if I run everything static my application runs on localhost, but it also won't load my css files neither the js files.

Where am i going wrong? all the regular path embedding didn't work like "/../index.html"

Comment: I think you may want to use `express.static`

Comment: This is a bad directory layout to make use of Express static file serving.  you want to reverse what you have and put the static resources like `main.html` into a sub-directory so you can point `express.static()` at that sub-directory and NOT accidentally serve any of your server files.

Answer (score 1):

Express response `sendFile()` method has a second options argument where you can express your root path for path resolution. See [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) for more information. You can use `{root: __dirname}` as second argument to `sendFile()` and file paths will be resolved relative to the javascript file that calls `sendFile()`. In your case with the directory structure indicated in your question the code on server.js would be:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile("../../main.html", {root: __dirname});
});
```

This way you can move your project to any folder and `sendFile()` will continue to work. I think you should reword your question because you are talking about absolute paths and not static paths.

Comment: thanks a lot yeiniel - i changed it. I'll try the different solutions in  the afternoon. thanks for your help so far

Comment: I removed my answer, +1

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do something like have two subfolders in the root of your project, one for server code and one for client (i.e. web) code and then you can use `app.use(express.static('<filepath>'))` in your server code to serve the static client files.

As an example, in my project root I have 2 folders, one called app and one called web.  In the main app.js, I have `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../web/'));` which serves the static content.  Normally this would be the first use of `app.use()` so that none of the other routes need to be checked before your content is served.